# What would you call a person who is being replaced by another

Tags: single-word-requests

In my specific case, I need a single word to call an employee who is being replaced by another due to his/her retirement, death, resignation etc.

Anything like “Replacee” may be suitable.

Comment: Why does it need to be a single word?  Give the person the dignity of saying "the person who retired/died/resigned/was fired."

Comment: @hot-licks In fact I have a group of columns containing information of superseding employees and i need to label this group of columns. Currently i am using "Outgoing Employees" , I thought it would be better if I could find a single word.

Comment: @Shahab: Replacement. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/replacement

Comment: A pod person.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pod_People_%28Invasion_of_the_Body_Snatchers%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One word is **Incumbent**

> adjective
>
> 1. holding an indicated position, role, office, etc., currently:
>
> *the incumbent officers of the club.*
>
> ...
>
> noun
>
> 4. the holder of an office:
>
> *The incumbent was challenged by a fusion candidate.*

Source: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/incumbent)

This word implies that the person being referred to is the *current* holder of the office or position, but might not hold it in the future.

Answer (score 7):

### Predecessor

A predecessor is exactly what you describe.  A person whom was replaced by another.

> Barack Obama's predecessor is George Bush Jr.

This word isn't exactly thrown around in everyday speech either.  It's usually reserved for higher up positions (like my presidential example).  That doesn't mean it couldn't be used for other jobs though.

> Jim Jones is the predecessor to the fry cook at Wendy's

meaning Jim Jones was the fry cook and has since been replaced.

*The person who replaced Jim Jones is called the **successor**, more particularly Jim Jones' successor.*

Comment: A is replaced by B.  So A says: "I had to train my replacement."  But B says: "My ______ had to train me."  Yes, I think "predecessor" will work here.

Answer (score 0):

The person that holds the position is the incumbent not a predecessor (predecessor implies the person before the one being replaced) the person that holds position or is being replaced is superseded by a successor if permanent or a (Temp) if not permanent position.

Comment: Hello, Old sch edu. 'Incumbent' might fit, but is certainly broader than 'an employee who is [shortly] being replaced by another due to his/her retirement, death, resignation etc.' The incumbent at any particular moment may never be replaced: the post may be discontinued.

Answer (score -2):

You can use **substitute**. In your example the new employee is a substitute for one who resigned the job.

The [Vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/substitute) describes the substitute as :

*Something or someone that takes the place of another is said to be a substitute. You may be sent into a game as a substitute for an injured player.*

Comment: You came up with an opposite(kind of) of what I wanted, I need title for the injured player in your example, which is being substituted.

Comment: He may be called shadow resource

Comment: This is the term I was looking fo:  Say candidate1 is absent, candidate2 replaces candidate1. So candidate2 is a substitute for candidate1. Thanks.

Answer (score -4):

Describing an employee being replaced because he/she died is a bit of a touchy subject, but I can think of one word that can cover everything:

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supersede):

> **supersede** (*verb*)
>   to take the place of : to replace

This seems adequate in the case of a deceased employee and would work fine for the other cases.
*The deceased employee was superseded by a newcomer.*

Comment: I would use "superseder" in this case I think. But not sure whom "superseder" would point to, employee being replaced or a newcomer?

Comment: @Shahab I recommend avoiding _superseder_. It's usage is tricky and it sounds odd. Here are two good options: (1) _The deceased employee was superseded by a newcomer._ (2) _The newcomer superseded the deceased employee._ The first sentence is passive which makes it less ideal. But to answer your question, _superseder_ would point to the newcomer.

Comment: I don't need to build a sentence. I need a label for superseding employees and single word would be better I think.

Comment: @Shahab How about _outbound_ or _withdrawing_?

Comment: Outbound seems good, but I still have to use "Employee" with it.

Comment: @Shahab Here are a bunch of great words I finally thought of: [_predecessor_](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/predecessor), [_precursor_](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/precursor), and [_forerunner_](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/forerunner). These all fit very well.